# Custom kernel giving an error ALERT! UUID=<my-/dev/sda5-uuid> does not exist. Dropping to shell

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, uuid

I have compiled and installed a custom kernel version in Ubuntu 22.04 by following the instructions in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

Now when I select my new customized kernel (5.15.0-68-generic) in Grub menu and try to boot up from that, it gives me following error and drop to a shell.

```
ALERT! UUID=<my UUID> does not exist. Dropping to shell.
```

I double checked the UUID above error prints and it is the correct UUID of my /dev/sda5 partition (root partition).
Also, my old kernel (5.19.0-35-generic) bootup without any issue when I select that in the Grub menu.
One thing to note here is that my **customized kernel is considerably slow than the original kernel (~8x) due to few debug features that I enabled.**

I noticed in similar scenarios people have suggested using rootdelay= as a boot option, I used rootdelay=600 as a boot option by editing the boot options in grub menu (by pressing e), but that also gave the same error.

I would really appreaciate any help related to this, thanks in advance.

**System information:**

Lenovo ThinkCentre M82, Intel I5-3470

Secure boot: Off

Intel virtualization and VT-d: On